# Windows Auth to external SQL DB from Docker ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker

I have Asp.net Project which is deployed through Docker Compose. The deployed application uses an external MS Sql database

If you deploy Asp.net Project locally, then the appsetting looks like using Windows Authentication:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
     "Database": "Data Source=name.server;Initial Catalog=name_base_dev;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
  },
  "DetailedErrors": true,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

However, if I deploy the Asp.net Project to Docker containers, I had to modify the appsetting because it doesn’t work otherwise (no database access) as:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
     "Database": "Data Source=name.server;Initial Catalog=name_base_dev;**User Id=name_user;Password=BigPassword**;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
  },
  "DetailedErrors": true,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

And all I see in docker container logs is this:

```
> Executing task: docker logs --tail 1000 -f d7d7fb508f6a0135b18ccfc40eecff1e3bab7e0cbcfdd6506d5d089acf5cd176 <

info: ProtoBuf.Grpc.Server.ServicesExtensions.CodeFirstServiceMethodProvider[0]
      RPC services being provided by Name_project.WebUi.Services.ApiService: 5
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
      Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.6 initialized 'Name_DbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.6' with options: MigrationsAssembly=Name_project.Persistence
info: ProtoBuf.Grpc.Server.ServicesExtensions.CodeFirstServiceMethodProvider[0]
      RPC services being provided by Name_project.WebUi.Services.ApiService: 5
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
      Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.6 initialized 'Name_DbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.6' with options: MigrationsAssembly=Name_project.Persistence
info: ProtoBuf.Grpc.Server.ServicesExtensions.CodeFirstServiceMethodProvider[0]
      RPC services being provided by Name_project.WebUi.Services.ApiService: 5
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
      Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.6 initialized 'Name_DbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.6' with options: MigrationsAssembly=Name_project.Persistence

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Help understand how to enable Windows Authentication for an Asp.net application deployed in Docker container.
Tried to specify Integrated Security=SSPI, also does not help.

### Updated 1

If I try to execute a command inside the container kinit nameuser -V -k -t /app/nameuser.keytab , then I get Authenticated to Kerberos v5

```
root@14f08a183079:/app# kinit nameuser -V -k -t /app/nameuser.keytab
Using default cache: /tmp/krb5cc_0
Using principal: nameuser@DOMAIN.LOCALL
Using keytab: /app/nameuser.keytab
Authenticated to Kerberos v5

root@14f08a183079:/app# klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: nameuser@DOMAIN.LOCAL

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
09/15/22 15:30:47  09/16/22 01:30:47  krbtgt/DOMAIN.LOCAL@DOMAIN.LOCAL
        renew until 09/22/22 15:29:47

root@14f08a183079:/app# kinit nameuser
```

If I try to run from Dockerfile, get in log app:

```
Start service
Using default cache: /tmp/krb5cc_0
Using principal: nameuser@DOMAIN.LOCAL
Using keytab: /app/nameuser.keytab
' not found while getting initial credentialsile '/app/nameuser.keytab
```

And all I see in docker container logs is this:

```
Using default cache: /tmp/krb5cc_0
Using principal: nameuser@DOMAIN.LOCAL
Using keytab: /app/nameuser.keytab
' not found while getting initial credentialsile '/app/nameuser.keytab
info: ProtoBuf.Grpc.Server.ServicesExtensions.CodeFirstServiceMethodProvider[0]
      RPC services being provided by MyProject.WebUi.Services.ApiService: 5
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
      Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.6 initialized 'ProjectDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.6' with options: MigrationsAssembly=MyProject.Persistence
Segmentation fault
```

Can You Help Me ?

Comment: Windows authentication means *not* using a username/password but connecting using the client process's account.

Comment: you can't use integrated security directly as the user account the asp server is running on would be the source of the integrated log on, which would be bad for many reasons, what you need is to pass through a log in token from the person using the asp service and pass that n to a the database driver as the active user

Comment: @MikeT, can I get a little more detail please.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow

Comment: generally i would create a application log in and use that to access the db, then if the user is authorised to use the application then it is assumed they are authorised to access the data that the application requires to operate, rather than risk a user who is authorised to access the app but not he data having the app falling over because it can't access its data. this also means that if somehow a user gains access directly to the database they can't see and change data that should only be available to them via an application

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Integrated Security by default from within a Docker container.

Your application does not run on Windows, it runs in Docker (probably Linux). Even if you'd use a Windows base image, that container is not in your domain, and/or it doesn't know about your SQL Server's host machine's Windows users, so it can't authenticate.

You can let the container use Kerberos to let it act like it belongs in the domain, but then you'll need to modify your Docker image so it does that.

See for example [Code Project: Authenticate .NET Core Client of SQL Server with Integrated Security from Linux Docker Container](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1272546/Authenticate-NET-Core-Client-of-SQL-Server-with-In) and [MS Docs: Understanding Active Directory authentication for SQL Server on Linux and containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-ad-auth-understanding?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: It's actually possible to use AD authentication both on Linux/MacOS and containers, using Kerberos. This is described in [Understanding Active Directory authentication for SQL Server on Linux and containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-ad-auth-understanding?view=sql-server-ver16). I've used this to connect from a company Mac to a SQL Server running on Windows using ADS. It's possible, but getting the configuration right needs "some" trial and error

Comment: There's also a guide for [various Linux flavors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-join-domain?view=sql-server-ver16). Once you get the configuration right, sure, you can use `kinit` before connecting, even on a separate machine. Getting there though was ... painful

Comment: @Panagiotis I believe that won't be trivial. The easy way out would be to enable SQL Server accounts.

Comment: Configured according to the instructions, but in the logs of the container get
Segmentation fault
' not found while getting initial credentialsile 'mynamekey.keytab

Comment: using integrated security in docker is easy, however the auth that would be integrated is the current active user, which is usually the system account that's running the web service, which is usually not an account that should have any access to the database. and enabling pass through security (where the service impersonates the user calling it rather than the account that is running it) tends to make more security issues than it solves